# __proto__ displaying only one inheritance in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was playing around with inheritance in javascript using NodeJS and I dont understand why **uncleTrump.__proto__.__proto__** only displays a single inheritance entity when multiply inheriting from two constructors.

Here is the code I was trying out .

```
const util = require('util')

function person(){
    this.species = 'human'
    this.planet  = 'earth'
}

function animal(){
    this.stupid = true
}

function boy(){
    animal.call(this)
    person.call(this)
    this.gender = 'male'
}


util.inherits(boy,person);
util.inherits(boy,animal);

let uncleTrump = new boy();
console.log(uncleTrump.__proto__.__proto__)
```

When this code is ran on using NodeJS the only output I receive is .

```
animal {}
```

Why cant I see person {} in the protype chain ?

Comment: What does `util.inherits` do? I think it's overwriting the `boy-person` prototype chain with `boy-animal`

Comment: `util.inherits`  allows you to attach a function to anothers prototype chain. I think you are correct, boy-animal might overwrite boy-person rather than forming a branch in the prototype chain . @adiga

Comment: I don't understand why you expect your prototype chain to appear like that. inherits just creates mixins, it doesn't extend the prototype

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript doesnt do multiple inheritance , it only supports a single inheritance model .
`util.inherits` overwrites **boy-person** prototype chain with **boy-animal** prototype chain .
Which is why I dont see  **person {}**   when `__proto__.__proto__` is called.

Comment: Exactly. It's a prototype chain, not a prototype tree :-)